# What happens when we use k=k-- in c++?

Tags: c++

I know that `k--` equals to `k = k - 1`. And I am wondering that what happens to `k = k--` which I think may cause infinite loop. But in fact, I compile this code in Visual Studio 2017 and the output of `k = k--` is the same as `k = k - 1`.

So what's the implication of `k = k--`?

Comment: Which C++ Standard are you targeting? Never mind VS 2017 targets C++14, yes?

Comment: Handy reading on the topic: [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) Warning: It goes on for a while.

Comment: GCC produce `eax = k; edx = eax - 1; k = edx; k = eax;`, which remains `k` unchanged.

Comment: Anyway, the kicker is as of C++17 this should be defined behaviour.

Comment: @user4581301 Ja, I'm already waiting for the new wave of confusion that will bring us. Btw sequece-points are gone since C++11.

Comment: Why would we want to "use `k = k--`" in the first place ?

Comment: @SidS It looks fancy.

Comment: You wouldn't. But as a Language Lawyer question it's a valid exploration of the language. I'm just waffling over whether or not I should dupe hammer it shut with [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Comment: @user4581301 Better not. This is a very specific question which already has a good answer by Jans.

Comment: Even before Jans'  answer I was angling that way. I'd much rather a short, specific answer than an answer buried in pages of general answers.

Comment: Looking through the [MSVS support table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2017), C++17 support looks pretty good in VS 2017 if your patching is up to date.

Comment: If you don't understand what it does, don't write it in production code. When you have to debug, you'll have to find out again. Use some extra characters to make it clear for everyone, including you in 6 months

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) the behavior was undefined, after that, It's fine according to [[expr.ass]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#1):

> [...] the assignment is sequenced after the value computation of the right and left operands, and before the value computation of the assignment expression. **The right operand is sequenced before the left operand**

and *sequenced before* means according to [[intro.execution]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#8)

> [...] An expression X is said to be sequenced before an expression Y if every value computation and every side effect associated with the expression X is sequenced before every value computation and every side effect associated with the expression Y.

In conclusion, `k=k-1` and `k=k--` are guaranteed to yield the same result.

also see: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Undefined_behavior)

Answer (score 4):

In C and C++ before C++17 [it is undefined behavior](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/153386/145). The fact that it gave a reasonable answer on your compiler is no guarantee that it will do so on other compilers, or even in other contexts with the current compiler.

Comment: Please add which language standard you are referring to.

Comment: @Swordfish The link is to a discussion of C and this answer went up back when the question was tagged with C or shortly after.

Comment: @user4581301 The link grazes C++ as well if you scroll down. Whats wrong with my request at AShelly to refine the answer by specifying which language standards don't define the behaviour?

Comment: @Swordfish Absolutely nothing. I just want to try and stave off a potential wave of downvotes.

Comment: downvote for answer being too general to be considered correct

Comment: @user4581301 Understood.